# Stabilisation of crossed modules?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, simplicial-stuff, crossed-modules

D. Conduché has introduced a notion of a stable crossed module ("Modules croisés généralisés de longueur 2", JPAA **34** (1984) pp155–178, doi:[10.1016/0022-4049(84)90034-3](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049%2884%2990034-3), Def. 3.1).

Is there a stabilisation functor from crossed modules to stable crossed modules?

Would it help to consider a crossed module equivalently as a group in categories and to try and define its abelianisation?

**Edit:** A stable crossed module consists of a group morphism $f : L\to M$ and a map $M\times M\to L$, $(m,m')\mapsto [[m,m']]$ such that:

- $f([[m,m']]) = [m,m']$,
- $[[f(\ell),f(\ell')]] = [\ell,\ell']$,
- $[[m',m]] = [[m,m']]^{-1}$, and
- $[[mm',m'']] = [[mm'm^{-1}, mm''m^{-1}]] \cdot [[m,m'']]$

for $\ell,\ell'\in L$ and $m,m',m''\in M$.
(Conduché writes $\{m,m'\}$ instead of $[[ m,m' ]]$.)

Using the action $\,^m\ell := [[m, f(\ell)]]\cdot \ell$ for $\ell\in L$ and $m\in M$, a stable crossed module is in particular a crossed module.

Stable crossed modules correspond to symmetric cat-groups, i.e. braided cat-groups with extra symmetry.

Comment: It would be helpful if you briefly gave the definition of stable crossed module.

Comment: Is not there a straightforward way? Given a crossed module $f:L\to M$, leave $M$ the same and extend $L$ to the free product $L*\operatorname{Free}(M\times M)$ modulo all the relations you need. This will give, more or less by definition, left adjoint to the forgetful functor from stable crossed modules to crossed modules.

Comment: The categories of (stable) crossed modules are locally presentable. Limits and filtered colimits are computed point-wise in both categories. Hence, the forgetful functor from stable crossed modules to crossed modules has a left adjoint. You can explicitly construct it in the way Mamuka suggests.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it! I'm a bit sceptical still because of the particular case $L=1$, where I would have expected the stabilisation of $1\to M$ to be $1\to M^\text{ab}$.

Comment: For $1\to M$ it must be $M\tilde\wedge M\to M$, its $\pi_0$ is $M^{\mathrm{ab}}$ but it also has $\pi_1$, namely $\pi_2^{\mathrm s}(BM)$, the second stable homotopy group of the classifying space of $M$, somehow justifying the word *stabilisation*.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!